# A Ham Sandwich type problem

Tags: algebraic-topology, lebesgue-measure, homology-cohomology

> If $A_1,...,A_n$ are measurable subsets of $S^n$, then there is a great $S^{n-1}$ cutting each $A_i$ exactly in half.

The tools I have at my disposal are the Borsuk Ulam theorem and the Ham Sandwich theorem.

My idea was to reduce it to the Ham Sandwich theorem as follows. View $S^n$ as $D^n/S^{n-1}$. Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be measurable subsets of $D^n/S^{n-1}$ and let's assume that they don't contain the $S^{n-1}$ which is collapsed to a point. So the $A_i's$ are subsets of $D^n\subset \Bbb{R}^n$. By the Ham Sandwich theorem, we choose a hyperplane that cuts each $A_i$ exactly in half. In the quotient space $D^n/S^{n-1}$, this hyperplane is a great $S^{n-1}$ cutting each $A_i$ in half.

Can we make this rigorous? Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the theorems do you have available?

Comment: The following: http://i.imgur.com/UnmsNH3.png and http://i.imgur.com/5dstyf4.png In fact, we have also proved a stronger version of Borsuk Ulam, namely that any map $S^n\to S^n$ preserving antipodes has odd degree.

Comment: What if some of $A_i$ contains $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: My idea was that $S^{n-1}$ has Lebesgue measure zero, so we should be able to make the reduction to the case that no $A_i$ intersects $S^{n-1}$. More explicitly, if $A_1,...,A_n$ are any measurable subsets of $D^n/S^{n-1}$, we consider the sets $B_i = A_i \cap (S^{n-1})^c$ and proceed to get a hyperplane cutting each $B_i$ exactly in half. This hyperplane should then also cut each $A_i$ exactly in half.

Comment: The trouble with your idea is that for $n\geq 2$ there isn't a homeomorphism $D^n/S^{n-1} \to S^n$ that maps hyperplanes in $D^n$ to great $S^{n-1}$'s in $S^n$.  To see this, observe that there are plenty of pairs of hyperplanes in $D^n$ that don't intersect, but every pair of great $S^{n-1}$'s in $S^n$ intersect along a great $S^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just apply Borsuk-Ulam theorem directly.

Define a function $f$ from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as follows:

If $x$ is a point on $S^n$, then there is a great $S^{n-1}$ that is orthogonal to the point $x$. The $S^{n-1}$ divides $S^n$ into two regions. Let's call them $U$ and $V$, where $U$ is the region containing $x$. If $\mu$ is the measure given, define $f(x)=(\mu(A_1\cup U), \ldots, \mu(A_n\cup U))$.

This is a continuous map from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, by Borsuk-Ulam theorem, there is a point $y$ such that $f(y)=f(-y)$. Then the great $S^{n-1}$ orthogonal to $y$ is the desired one.